# How to record (accepting and later returning) other peoples' money? What's the correct terminology for that? // GnuCash

Tags: gnucash, bookkeeping

How to record (accepting and later returning) **other peoples' money** in `GnuCash`?

- I assume it would *not* be recorded as **income / expense**, respectively.
- **Liabilities** also seems unlikely.
- **Equities**? Maybe...
- **Assets** seems the most likely candidate.

But I'm just guessing wildly... Could not find anything relevant on Google, neither :(

---

Also, what's the correct terminology for:

- the **account**: custody / (lawyer/notary) trust / escrow / fiduciary / suspense
- the **money**: other peoples' money (OPM) / third-party funds
- the **booking entry/entires**: pass-through / temporary / transitory item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the official solution satisfying int'l convention / legislation, but at least has *some* logic to it (though I myself am not 100% convinced as yet):

- **Liabilities !**

  ... but is it *really* a liability?

---

Rationale:

- Someone gives me their money (just to look after it, say for a week; no interest, ROI, etc).
- Ups my bank account statement and/or my cash-in-hand/wallet.
- And simultaneously ups my liabilities: since what difference does it make if I borrow some money (to use it or not use it, repay later) or if someone just wants to "store" some money with me: w.r.t. balance sheet I'd say: zero...

  ... with the one caveat that it might make a difference w.r.t. **taxation** ?

Answer (score 3):

There are four sides to this transaction.

You increase in money: A debit. (increases your **Current Assets**, if you will)
You also gain the requirement to pay that money in the future. A credit: Definitely a **Liability**.

When you repay the money, your cash will *decrease*: a credit, and your liabilities will also decrease, which is a debit (since you don't have to repay the money anymore).

the account would be short-term loans, the money doesn't have a name, it's just cash and would go into whatever cash accounts you have. The bookkeeping entry would be the same as you would make for any short-term loan.

Comment: I was suggesting `Liabilities` in my original question (and answer, a day before yours). Now what you highlight in your answer is `Liabilities`, too. What then makes you state "*none of the accounts you highlighted seem correct*" ?

Comment: You've edited your question since I posted that. Previously you had a list of different accounts to book it under. (Either that or I misread the second half of your question). Liabilities is not an account, it is a type of account

Comment: All my edits were prior to your answer. Which was after I figured the concept out myself. Terminology is still outstanding.